# Как добавить возможность пагинации в Symfony?

Tags: symfony

Есть роут `@Route("/products/", name="products")`

Возвращает все продукты.

Но нужно добавить так же возможность пагинации, когда будет работать `/products/20/0` - limit и offset.

Как сделать, чтобы был доступен роут и **/products** и **/products/20/0** ?

Comment: Всегда пользуюсь этим бандлом https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: `Как сделать, чтобы был доступен роут и /products и /products/20/0 ?`

Добавить значения по-умолчанию.